Hom between simple module and sign module of symmetric group
I am reading the paper [1]. Let K be the field of characteristic p. If $p \geq 4$ and $p \nmid n-1$ then $\mathrm{Hom}_{KS_n} (D^{(n-1,1)}, \mathrm{sgn})=0$.
Why the above statement is true?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Are you asking why there is no non-trivial homomorphism between two non-isomorphic simple modules?
